# split element inside list by comma with python

Tags: python

```
myList = ['Jay', 'Phil', 'Gloria, Claire']
```

I want to check every element in the list and split by comma, making the two new elements stay in the same list. Output should be:

```
myList = ['Jay', 'Phil', 'Gloria', 'Claire']
```

I've tried this:

```
newList = []
myList = ['Jay', 'Phil', 'Gloria, Claire']

for element in myList:
   newList.append(element.split(','))
```

but I got as output a lot of sub lists and this is not what I want:

```
['Jay'], ['Phil'], ['Gloria', 'Claire']
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: How do you want to split by a delimiter that is not in your string?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `extend` instead of `append`.

```
for element in myList:
   newList.extend(element.split(','))
```

Comment: You're going to end up with an unwanted to space with `"thing, that".split(',')`

Comment: @idjaw I took care of that in my answer

Answer (score 2):

I can recomend you to use list comprehension:

```
newList = [element for item in myList for element in item.split(',')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have one major error

**First:** Appending a list to a list properly requires a different approach (using += vs. append)

Then you need to use 'strip' to remove the white space in ', Claire' to get 'Claire' (not ' Claire')

```
newList = []
myList = ['Jay', 'Phil', 'Gloria, Claire']

for element in myList:
   newList += element.split(',')

newList = [x.strip() for x in newList]

print newList

# ['Jay', 'Phil', 'Gloria', 'Claire']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is good for different problem.

if:

```
myList = "Jay,Phil,Gloria,Claire"
```

it's make sense to spilt the string to list of words.

Currently you already have a list of words so you split it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension works well in these case

```
subList = [elem.split(',') for elem in mylist]
newList = [l for elem in subList for l in elem]
```